# PHP Function return 0 vs false

Tags: php

I have a PHP function which returns a number that can be zero or larger. For example:

```
public function returnVal($val1, $val2) {
  if ($val2 > $val1) return $val2 - $val1;
  else return false;
}
```

This is being used as:

```
if ($diff = $this->returnVal($a, $b)) // do something
else // don't
```

However when the difference is zero, i'd still like it to do something, however it seems to be detecting the zero as false rather than zero. I still need to know when it is false though.

I tried changing it to:

```
if (($val2 - $val1) == 0) return 'zero';
if ($val2 > $val1) return $val2 - $val1;
else return false;
```

Which does work, but seems a bit inelegant - surely there must be a better way?

Thanks

Comment: `$diff = $this->returnVal($a, $b); if ($diff !== false) // do something
else // don't`

Comment: Wrap your test in [`is_int()`](http://php.net/is_int), or alternatively the common ugly `!== false` check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the variable assignment shortcut inside of an if-statement, PHP uses loose-type comparisons and type-juggles things like `0`, `null`, and other false-y values to `false`. You must use use the explicit `===` and `!==` comparisons to ensure that the comparison is of the exact same type (*without* type-juggling):

```
$diff = $this->returnVal($a, $b);
if ($diff !== false) // do something
else // don't
```

See [this reference](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for all of the comparison conditions that could occur from using simple `==`, `=`, or `!=` comparisons.

Alternative from @MrLlama:

```
if (($diff = $this->returnVal($a, $b)) !== false) // do something
else // don't
```

Comment: Ah ok, i've played with === before but had soem strange results, probably from not returning the correct type though. I guess I was trying to do it without assigning it to a temporary variable as well, but just tested it and it works so many thanks :)

Comment: @stukerr You're welcome! Hope the reference to the docs cleared some things up for you. After the appropriate amount of time has lapsed, please make sure you mark the answer that helped you best as accepted.

Comment: You can also use `if ( ($var = func($a, $b)) !== FALSE )` but it's not as clean.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Yeah I prefer to leave those kind of shortcuts out unless it's simple

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Llama - always nice to know the shortest way as well